# SQLite file unable to be found, even though it is in directory EXPO

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

I have been trying to connect my SQLite DB with my Expo file and have been reading some documentation online to get a good basis and understanding so that I could begin my own coding. I ran across this example snack linked here: https://snack.expo.io/SJ99BIfrX. However, when I downloaded the file onto the EXPO XDE, but I got this error message: 'Unable to resolve "./assets/db/test.sqlite" from "App.js"', even though the file is clearly in the assets/db/ file.

I have been really frustrated trying to figure it out, so anyone help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try 'c:/your_project_dir/assets/db/test.sqlite' where c is the drive in which your project is found. Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution?